# Crystal Report using sub-reports with the same table

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, subreport

Is it possible to have 3 sub-reports that come from the same table? I have to do 1 main report and 3 sub-reports.

Example.
       Mainreport :       Product Name
           Sub-report 1 : Customer Name
                          Customer Phone
           Sub-report 2 : Product No
                          product Detail
           Sub-report 3 : Owner Name
                          Owner Detail

Actually I have one table and need to display fields in 3 category so I decided to have 3 sub-reports. I am not sure what I have decided is correct?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misusing Sub-reports.  In Crystal Reports (7+), Sub-reports should be used to data in the report that is *related* to the primary query, but that you may not want to "Join" in with your primary dataset, for performance reason or otherwise.

I use sub-reports to include a list of records that are 1:M to the current row, but I want to show them in the detail section without adding a group to my report.

In your case, it seems that you have different classification of fields in your Product table and you want to show them "grouped" together relatively.  I would suggest creating multiple details sections and perhaps drawing some lines in the report to separate and differentiate the sections of data.

That said, you CAN create a report with 3 sub-reports for this, but you would be essentially taking the long way to load each product in your set 4 times (once for the primary report and the once per sub).

Let me know if there are questions.

Comment: Do I need to group them? I mean, do I have to create a group for each of classification?

Comment: No need to group unless the query calls for it.  You can understand this with a simple analogy with a SQL statement and results.  If you write a SQL statement to get your data, and the statement doesnt contain a "GROUP BY" and all of your data you want to show is in a single row, then you dont need a sub-report or a group.  You just need to create a bunch of sections and work on your layout and alignment skills

Comment: Is this ok? if I have a several Product Name? Will it repeat automatically?  My goal is to have Product Name as a head of 3 classification and of course I have more than one Product Name.